# All encoders failed to encode metasploit

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to use this exploit on HTB : https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi

pretty simple yet metasploit gives me an error : all encoders failed to encode

I have spent hours trying to find a solution but I found nothing :/

This is screenshot for the error https://ibb.co/sQ5cCFY

Metasploit version is 6.0.2-dev

Any solutions or steps to debug this?

Comment: Try setting the target os